# python boolean value to json string with quote

Tags: python, json, quote

all,

I encounter an issue with a requirement. I know normally when change python boolean to json format, then gonna use the solution as below:

```
>>>data = {'key1': True}
>>>data_json = json.dumps(data)
>>>print data_json
{'key1': true}
```

The issue I have is that I need to have it as {'key1': 'true'}, string with quote ' or double quote ". Anyone knows is there any correct and simple way to do that? Thanks

Zhihong

Comment: I'm curious about why you'd need booleans to be converted into strings. Are you feeding a very weird API?

Comment: Is this a pretty predictable dataset where you could simply do `{'key1': 'true' if True else 'false'}`? Or some potentially deep nested structure with arbitrary values?

Comment: well the correct way is without quotes... if you need to add quotes for some reason then you have to process it manually and add it yourself

Comment: Hi, Felk, yes, that is a API requirement that I send the data to, the example data does need quote. I am still testing whether that is the reason. Actually, The data can be sent without error when I just use original True or False. But the support guy said the value is not correct set. And after change to use true and false, then I got API error.

Comment: @deceze, it is not complex structure by now. But maybe some nested structure in the future, so I would like a good solution.

Comment: @lapinkoira, thanks, that is something I would like to be sure of. If can only process manually, then I will do like that.

Answer (score 1):

Before calling `json.dumps(data)`, process your data accordingly:

```
for key in data:
    if type(data[key]) is bool:
        data[key] = str(data[key]).lower()
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer.

Answer (score 1):

If your keys are not nested, then it's just a simple operation of `str(value).lower()`, otherwise you'd have to do it recursively.

```
# this should work for basic data types

def convert_booleans(value):
    if isinstance(value, dict):
        return {key: convert_booleans(val) for key, val in value.items()}
    elif isinstance(value, bool):
        return str(value).lower()
    elif hasattr(value, '__iter__'):
        return map(convert_booleans, value)

    return value

converted_data = convert_booleans(data)
print(json.dumps(converted_data))
```

With that said, it is not an ideal thing to do. JSON object has a special meaning for the boolean value, and it shouldn't be treated as a string. You had better try to convince the client of your api if possible. Most likely, the client is processing the result data as a string and not json, and hence finding it difficult to parse the data.

Comment: thanks for the quick answer. Yes, I think then I need process this case separately. Thanks